# How to select a specific table using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been searching around for a while and I can't find the answer for this.

I'm trying to webscrape the "Results by State" table available on Wikipedia  on the link below:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state

So  far when I run my code I can only get it  to  pull the data from the "Joe Biden vs Donald Trump" table further up the page.

```
website = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election'

result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find("table", class_="wikitable sortable")
for table in tables:
    if 'Results by state' in table.text:
        headers = [header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th')]
        rows = []
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')    
        for row in table_rows:
           td = row.find_all('td')
           row = [row.text for row in td]
           rows.append(row)
```

Comment: `.find()` only finds the **first** matching element.  Perhaps you wanted `.find_all()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small issue in your code while getting the table you are using find() method to get the table
tables = soup.find("table", class_="wikitable sortable")
Because of this the script is taking the first table element that matches the classname and returns it in your case it was returning the joe binden vs trump
You can fix this issue by using find_all() method
final_all will return the list of all the tags that matches the classname

Here is the code with changes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election'

result = requests.get(website,timeout=100)
content = result.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="wikitable sortable")
for table in tables:
    if 'Results by state' in table.text:
        headers = [header.text.strip() for header in table.find_all('th')]
        rows = []
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')    
        for row in table_rows:
           td = row.find_all('td')
           row = [row.text for row in td]
           rows.append(row)
        print(headers)
        print(rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask what is the strip() doing (I know what the function does but I'm trying to understand in this context)?

Comment: strip is used to remove any leading or trailing spaces

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to scrape tables would be to use `pandas.read_html()` and try to match a pattern in a table:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election', match='Results by state')[0]
```

Using `BeautifulSoup` directly try to select your table more specific e.g. with `css selectors`:

```
tables = soup.select('table:has(caption:-soup-contains("Results by state"))')
```